# Access violation reading location 0xCDCDCDD1

Tags: c++, exception, visual-studio-2013, heap-memory

I am using Visual Studio 2013. I am getting the `Access violation reading location 0xCDCDCDD1` error. References from [Wikipedia: Magic Numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29), [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/38440/), and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17993591/c-access-violation-reading-location-0xcdcdcdcd-error-on-calling-a-function) tell me that I am using an uninitialized pointer. I think the problem is with the `malloc` function I'm using, although I did refer to the [CPlusPlus](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/) doc before using it.

My code:

```
#include "SingleNode.h"
#include "SingleList.h"
#include <iostream>
SingleList::SingleList() {}
SingleList::~SingleList() {}
...
    void SingleList::addHead(int value){
    ISingleNode *temp1 = (ISingleNode *)malloc(sizeof(SingleList));
    head = NULL;
    temp1->setValue(value);
    temp1->setNext(head->getNext());
    if (!head->getNext())
    {
        head = temp1;
    }
    else
    {
        temp1->setNext(head->getNext());
        head = temp1;
    }
}

    ...
```

The error is in the line `temp1->setValue(value);`

The `setValue(int value)` function is included from here:

```
#include "SingleNode.h"
SingleNode::SingleNode() {}
SingleNode::~SingleNode() {}
void SingleNode::setValue(int value){
    this->value = value;
}
int SingleNode::getValue(){
    return value;
}
ISingleNode * SingleNode::getNext(){
    return next;
}
void SingleNode::setNext(ISingleNode * next){
    this->next = next;
}
```

SingleNode.h:

```
#pragma once
#include "Interfaces01.h"
class SingleNode :public ISingleNode{
private:
    int value;
    ISingleNode * next = NULL;
public:
    SingleNode();
    ~SingleNode();
    void setValue(int value);
    int getValue();
    ISingleNode * getNext();
    void setNext(ISingleNode * next);
};
```

SingleList.h:

```
#pragma once
#include "Interfaces01.h"
class SingleList :public ISingleList{
private:
    int value;
    ISingleNode * head=NULL;
    ISingleNode * temp=NULL;
    ISingleNode * next=NULL;
    ISingleNode * temp1;
public:
    SingleList();
    ~SingleList();
    ISingleNode * getHead();
    void setHead(ISingleNode * head);
    void addHead(int value);
    void orderSort2();
    void orderSort3();
    void sequenceOrderSort();
    void reverse();
    ISingleNode * swap(ISingleNode * head, int k);
    ISingleNode * get_node(ISingleNode * head, int k);
};
```

On breaking at the line, the debugger is showing me the following values:

[image: Visual Studio 2013 debug values at breakpoint]

Comment: Why are you use C library calls such as `malloc` in C++ ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/127404/487892

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Change:

   ```
   ISingleNode *temp1 = (ISingleNode *)malloc(sizeof(SingleList));
   ```

   into:

   ```
   ISingleNode *temp1 = new SingleList;
   ```
2. You are accessing a `NULL` pointer:

   ```
   head = NULL; // set to NULL
   temp1->setValue(value);
   temp1->setNext(head->getNext()); // oops!
   ```

   you probably meant:

   ```
   void SingleList::addHead(int value)
   {
       ISingleNode *temp1 = new SingleList;
       temp1->setValue(value);
       temp1->setNext(head);
       head = temp1;
   }
   ```