# How can I display a bitmap based on byte array using MFC (visual C++ 2015)?

Tags: c++, mfc

I try to display a bitmap (gray image) by using MFC but failed. I am using standard windows API in my MFC codes. Below is the code (view.cpp and I put own code in `::OnDraw()`):

`lpBits` is the `BYTE` array contains the bitmap `BYTE` data.
When I run the code, I got an "exception thrown" error message and no display of the bitmap (a black bitmap image).
Below you can find the code as well as the error message.

```
extern BYTE lpBits[510][1024 * 4] = { 0 };
extern CRITICAL_SECTION g_cs;
```

---

```
View.h:

class Cmfc_gui_test1View : public CView
{
protected: // create from serialization only
    Cmfc_gui_test1View();
    DECLARE_DYNCREATE(Cmfc_gui_test1View)

// Attributes
public:
    Cmfc_gui_test1Doc* GetDocument() const;

// Operations
public:

// Overrides
public:
    virtual void OnDraw(CDC* pDC);  // overridden to draw this view
    virtual BOOL PreCreateWindow(CREATESTRUCT& cs);
protected:
    virtual BOOL OnPreparePrinting(CPrintInfo* pInfo);
    virtual void OnBeginPrinting(CDC* pDC, CPrintInfo* pInfo);
    virtual void OnEndPrinting(CDC* pDC, CPrintInfo* pInfo);

// Implementation
public:
    virtual ~Cmfc_gui_test1View();
#ifdef _DEBUG
    virtual void AssertValid() const;
    virtual void Dump(CDumpContext& dc) const;
#endif

protected:

// Generated message map functions
protected:
    afx_msg void OnFilePrintPreview();
    afx_msg void OnRButtonUp(UINT nFlags, CPoint point);
    afx_msg void OnContextMenu(CWnd* pWnd, CPoint point);
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()

public:
    CBitmap* pBitmap;
    CDC*    pcdcMem;
    CDC*    m_pDC;
    CRect   crect;
    CWnd*   pwndParent;
    int screenX;
    int screenY;
    afx_msg int OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct);
};
```

---

```
View.cpp:
// Cmfc_gui_test1View drawing

void Cmfc_gui_test1View::OnDraw(CDC* pDC)
{
    Cmfc_gui_test1Doc* pDoc = GetDocument();
    ASSERT_VALID(pDoc);
    if (!pDoc)
        return;

    // TODO: add draw code for native data here

    screenX = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
    screenY = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);

    pBitmap->CreateCompatibleBitmap(m_pDC, 1024, 510);  // Error here
    
    pBitmap->SetBitmapBits(510*1024*4, lpBits);

    pcdcMem->CreateCompatibleDC(m_pDC);
    pcdcMem->SelectObject(pBitmap);
    
    m_pDC->StretchBlt( 0, 0, screenX, screenY, pcdcMem, 0, 0, 1024, 510, SRCCOPY);

    pDC->DeleteDC();
}


// Cmfc_gui_test1View message handlers


int Cmfc_gui_test1View::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
{
    if (CView::OnCreate(lpCreateStruct) == -1)
        return -1;

    // TODO:  在此添加您专用的创建代码
    m_pDC = new CClientDC(this);

    return 0;
}
```

Error message occurs when execution hits the line `pBitmap->CreateCompatibleBitmap(m_pDC, 1024, 510);`:

```
0x0F7C0AEA (mfc140d.dll)处(位于 mfc_gui_test1.exe 中)引发的异常: 0xC0000005: 读取位置 0xCDCDCDD1 时发生访问冲突。

如有适用于此异常的处理程序，该程序便可安全地继续运行。
```

Translated:

```
Exception thrown at 0x0F7C0AEA (mfc140d.dll) (in mfc_gui_test1.exe): 0xC0000005: Access violation while reading location 0xCDCDCDD1.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program can safely continue running.
```

Comment: It looks like you have a lot of irrelevant code in your example. (E.g., why all those functions related to printing?) Your code should be laser-focused on just what is needed to reproduce the error, a.k.a. a [mre]. Please remove the noise.

Comment: Done of the removing those irrelvant codes and adding the error message info.

Comment: That is better. Now a bad translation won't interfere with getting help. The error is not "an interrupt of the exception", but an unhandled exception. Furthermore, the exception is not the thing to focus on -- the core error is the second part, "Access violation while reading location [uninitialized pointer]". This is a reason why the original error message should be included verbatim in a question here, even when the message is not in English. (It's also a good idea to provide an English translation to help people get started answering.)

Comment: As for your code, it looks like you've trimmed off too much, as `pBitmap` has no declaration. (Also, it has no initialization, but that might be the case in your code as well.) A good next step is identifying which line triggers the access violation. Then focus on that line. Make sure everything used in that line has a definition, and include any initialization that is performed on those things.

Comment: Hi thanks for highlighting this. Sorry that I delete too much. Now I added ::OnCreate section. I've got the program verified that the line trigger the error is:  pBitmap->CreateCompatibleBitmap(m_pDC, 1024, 510); I also replace all m_pDC with pDC in OnDraw function. No lucky to see any improvement.

Comment: Yes, the translation of the error message is:   "Exception thrown at 0x0FC40AEA (mfc140d.dll) (in mfc_gui_test1.exe): 0xC0000005: Access violation while reading location 0xCDCDCDD1.
If there is a handler for this exception, the program can safely continue running." Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: By using CClientDC dc(this) and using dc to replace pDC , now I can have a normal display of a black screen in my client window. The result is what I want. Now looks my initial issue is fail to connect "this" to pDC pointer. Can someone highlight it to me? What is "this" ? Thanks.

Comment: *"Now I added ::OnCreate section."* -- that's good, but there is still no initialization of `pBitmap`. So that is most likely your issue. See [Access violation reading location 0xcdcdcdcd error on calling a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17993591/c-access-violation-reading-location-0xcdcdcdcd-error-on-calling-a-function)

Comment: Thanks JaMiT ! It is fixed by implementing: CBitmap* pBitmap=new CBitmap;  Now pBitmap is not a float pointer. Thanks for your help!